# is there any way to stop/log http request in android?

Tags: android, sockets, http, networking, android-networking

is there any app or way to log or temper http request even edit it ?
i tried some proxy apps but it did not work any help plz. 
if there any app dose not Asks for a root.
and what about if I put the emulator(bluestackes) in a sand box like wireshark?

Answer (score 1):

Yea, HTTP GET

```
public static InputStream getInputStreamFromUrl(String url) {
    InputStream content = null;
    try {
          HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
          HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
          content = response.getEntity().getContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.("[GET REQUEST]", "Network exception", e);
    }
    return content;
}

// see http://androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-get-request-with-httpclient
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try this one out. It doesn't seem to support editing, though.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.taosoftware.android.packetcapture